# I can't root my OPPO Neo 5 (2015)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, root-access, oppo-coloros

So I came a lot of steps to root my OPPO Phone, Installed KingRoot in Android but failed to root, then tried the PC Version (Higher Success Rate) but still failed to root, I also tried KingoRoot, and got same results with KingRoot in Android And PC, and also I tried this Vroot (iRoot) but still did not solve this. I also tried  [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2684210)  thread but I'm stuck at ADB Devices which returns me offline devices. And lastly installing Custom Recovery but the problem is, my device is not supported. So is there any way (longer way) to do it with PC ?  Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can downgrade your version to 1201EX-A_11_151230 then try to root it with kingroot. Just search for tutorials.